# Putting an async function into a variable

Tags: web3js

I would like to pull the latest gasUsed from a block. When I run a `console.log` I get the required output in the terminal. However, I am trying to use the gasUsed from the latest block and put that into a variable so I can use it elsewhere. Any thought?

```
dotenv.config();

const Web3 = require("web3");
const web3 = new Web3("https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/" + process.env.INFURA_KEY);

web3.eth.getBlock("latest").then(console.log);
let gasUsedLast = web3.eth.getBlock("latest").then((blockInfo) => {
  console.log(blockInfo.gasUsed);
  return blockInfo.gasUsed;
});

console.log(gasUsedLast);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
Const gasUsed = async()=>{
       const result = await web3.eth.getblock("latest")
       
       return result }
;(async()=>{
       const gasFees = await gasUsed()
       console.log(gasFees) }
```

The function would look something like this. I'm also learning solidity & ether but this is how i would do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think Wallet has to be a var not a const - you can’t update or re-declare a const. So:

```
dotenv.config();

var Web3 = require("web3");
var web3 = new Web3("https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/" + process.env.INFURA_KEY);

web3.eth.getBlock("latest").then(console.log);
let gasUsedLast = web3.eth.getBlock("latest").then((blockInfo) => {
  console.log(blockInfo.gasUsed);
  return blockInfo.gasUsed;
});

console.log(gasUsedLast);
```

Comment: Using `var` instead of `const` just changes the scoping rules applied. The promise behavior won't change.